# How to add an icon in the tab of a new document ? (dockpanel-suite)

Tags: dockpanel-suite

Maybe some one can help me or tell me how to add an icon in the tab of a new document in "DockPanel Suite" ? Or what is the best way to do this ? Thank you in advance for your help and feedback. Regards, Daniel

(Another point. It will be nice to do that with VS2012 Light theme. Thank you in advance. Daniel)

Comment: Aaaaaand what have you attempted?

Comment: Hello Harry, I tried a lot of things. But I am beginer and I come here to have advices or helps. Rgds, Daniel

Comment: Understood, but perhaps include what you've tried so we don't repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set `DockContent.Icon` to the icon you want (similar to set `Icon` of a normal `Form`).
2. Set `DockPanel.ShowDocumentIcon` to `true`.

If you look for a sample, this Compiler project uses this feature,

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/tree/51773488fcb7b9714a38134187363fef5762daca/Compiler

To get VS2012 theme, make sure that

1. You use our 3.0 NuGet package or build from `development_3.0` branch, https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/tree/development_3.0
2. Create a new instance of `VS2012LightTheme` class and assign it to `DockPanel.Theme`.

This has been demonstrated in DockSample project of DockPanel Suite,

https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite/blob/development_3.0/DockSample/MainForm.cs

You can see the changes needed in `SetSchema` method.

Note that all existing `DockContent` objects should be cleaned before changing themes.

Comment: Good morning Li, Great, thank you very much for your fast response... It works well ;) Thank you again. Anyway, do you know how to operate it with the VS2012Light skin ? Of course it's the one I need. lol. Thank you in advance for your reply. Rgds, Daniel

Comment: @Li Hello Li, Thank you for your help. I appreciate. Maybe I'm not have been clear enough, sorry. Anyway, my problem now is that I cannot display icons in tabs when I use the theme VS2012Light. it works with other themes, but not with VS2012Light. Thank you in advance for your help and for your patience. Rgds, Daniel. PS. Sorry for my English

Comment: I have checked in a new change set on GitHub which fixed this issue. You might build a new copy from development_3.0 branch and test it out.

Comment: @Li Hello Li, Thank you, thank you... It works fine now... I realy appreciate your availability.. Again, BRAVO for your works on DockPanel Suite. Greetings